# .FillText() doesn't work in simple JavaScript game

Tags: javascript, canvas

I created a simple vanilla JS(and html canvas) game. In this game marbles are flying from right to left and you have to click on them until they pass left border of your screen.

PROBLEM:
I created 2 functions, one is a message(**drawGameOver**) that I want to show when you lose, the other is the message(**drawPromo**) I want to show when score reaches +20 points.

My game over message does not work as expected - the fillText is not showing anything

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/j7mbtnvL/ (it works kinds funky on jsfiddle but it works fine on  the browser)

```
function animate(timestamp) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    collisionCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // timestamp z nowego loop minus timestamp z ostatniego loop
    let deltatime = timestamp - lasttime;
    lasttime = timestamp;
    timeToNextBall += deltatime;
    if (timeToNextBall > ballInterval){
        balls.push(new Ball());
        timeToNextBall = 0;
        balls.sort(function(a,b){
            return a.width - b.width;
        });
    };
    drawScore();
    [...balls, ...explosions].forEach(object => object.update());
    [...balls, ...explosions].forEach(object => object.draw());
    //usuwanie starych klatek
    balls = balls.filter(object => !object.markedForDeletion);
    explosions = explosions.filter(object => !object.markedForDeletion);
    if (!gameOver) requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    else drawGameOver();
    if (score > 20) drawPromo;
}
animate(0);
```

game actually stops when you lose but drawGameOver doesn't appear on the screen. So it seems to me like I did something weird at the very end of animate function

```
if (!gameOver) requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  else drawGameOver();
  if (score > 20) drawPromo;
```

Comment: you blit text out of canvas bound, at canvas.width and canvas.height position, set it at hard fixed position by exemple > https://jsfiddle.net/vp62s4hd/

Comment: Your code work fine for me I do see the text on screen when drawGameOver is called